Can muslims use MDMA as a medical treatment?
The Hadith seems clear:

There is no disease that Allah has created, except that He also has
created its treatment.

This basically means that islam allows treatments of diseases. It is something good created by Allah
Science also seems clear: MDMA is an effective part of some medical treatments.

These data suggest that MDMA-AT reduced PTSD symptoms and functional
impairment in a diverse population with moderate to severe PTSD and
was generally well tolerated.

And is therefore approved in several countries as such.
This seems logical. It helps people who are suffering from a terrible disease.
Helping such people is a good thing according to the Hadith:

The one who looks after a widow or a poor person is like a Mujahid who
fights for Allah's Cause, or like him who performs prayers all the
night and fasts all the day.

So can we conclude that islam allows (under certain circumstances) the use of MDMA?
I am aksing because when I google on this topic, I read a lot about people saying that it is not allowed.

It is fundamentally different. A term like "necessary" is meaningless. People who use MDMA often say it is "necessary", regardless of wether they use it on a party or in a hospital.  "haram ingredients" is a bit vague. MDMA is not mentioned in the Quran as a "haram ingredient". The question you refer to simply cannot be answered properly.  However, this question is very clear and specific. That is how it differs.

We are not a fatwa site. If using it impairs judgement and removes inhibitions similar to wine then it should be haram, a hadith says  كل مسكر حرام - if it is haram then the ruling on using something haram as medicine is covered in the linked duplicate.
